# How to convert web service response input stream to java object?

Tags: java, web-services, json, cxf, jax-rs

Upon executing a http request on my web serivce, I get a `javax.ws.rs.core.Response` object. When I call the `getEntity` method on the `Response` object I get an input stream, which is a string representation of JSON. Does anyone know how I can/should convert this string into a java object? Since, I'm using CXF can I use the JAXBContext? Or must I create a custom message body reader? Thanks.

Comment: I'd created WebService client to consume it

Answer (score 1):

[Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) has built-in JAX-RS support.
See org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider
and org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider

Answer (score 1):

This is an example. It will help someone some day. (This is using a sample XML Input)

```
    @POST
    @Path("/unmarshall")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public Response unmarshall(InputStream inputStream) throws JAXBException {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyJaxbClass.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        Object unmarshal = unmarshaller.unmarshal(inputStream);
        return Response.ok().entity(unmarshal).build();
    }
```